# Creating a Time Range in SQL

Tags: sql, hive

I want to make a table (Table A) in Hive that has three columns. This table has times starting from 5AM and ending at 2AM the next day. Each row is a 5 minute increment from the previous row.

The first two columns are this (and I don't know how to generate this).

```
start_time | end_time
  5:00:00  |  5:05:00
  5:05:01  |  5:10:00
 ... 
 23:55:01  | 00:00:00
 ... 
  1:55:01  | 02:00:00
```

Does anyone know how to do the above?

To shed some background:

Once I have Table A created, I want to use use another table (Table B) that I have with epoch times for each record that represents a visit of a customer, extract the necessary hour/minute/second information, and then provide a sum count of visitors for each time interval in a third column of Table A, say, "customer_count".

I think I know to do the calculation for "customer_count" column for Table A, however, what I need help with is making the first two columns in Table A.

Comment: Would something like this help? http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1081297/Split-time-with-mins-interval-in-sql-server

Comment: @Aron: Thanks for the tip! I believe recursive CTEs are not supported in Hive. I tried a method that utilizes it that I think I found in SO before I posted.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the other way around:

1. Crop from table B the dates you are interested in
2. Group by 5 minute increments (calculated by `(time-start_time) / 60 / 5` assuming the epoch is in seconds)
3. Then turn the increments back into dates and calculate the second `end_time` column

Something like this:

```
select from_unixtime(<start time> + period*60*5),
        from_unixtime(<start time> + (period+1)*60*5),
        count from
  (select (time-<start time>)/(60*5) as period,count(*) as count from tableB 
    where time >= <start time> and time <= <end time> 
    group by (time-<start time>)/(60*5) ) inner
```

Note that you won't receive times with zero count (no visits during a period)

Comment: Hi Alex, just wanted to thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: Hi @smali, if you are happy with an answer, you can accept it - the green check mark near the answer.